# Linq Query - how can you improve the following query?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a Linq To Sql query in my asp.net website.

This query works too **Slow** and im sure that it can be improved.

**Can anyone help me ReWrite this query?**

I assume using "join" would make it quicker but couldn't get it right. :(

---

Here is the query: (input params : INT_GENDER )

```
var users = from u in db.Users
            where (u.gender == INT_GENDER) && (u.age > 25)
            let fileId = (from f in db.Files 
                         where f.username == u.username && f.approved 
                         orderby f.primary 
                         select f.id).FirstOrDefault()
            let answer = (from a in db.Answers
                           where (a.username == u.username) && 
                                 (a.q_id == (from q in db.Questions where q.type == 1
                                                  select q.id).FirstOrDefault()) &&
                                  a.approved

                          select a).FirstOrDefault()

select new { 

    Username = u.u_username,
    FileId = fileId !=null ? fileId : GetEmptyFileId(),
    Answer = (answer == null ? "" : (answer.approved ? answer.value: "Empty"))
};
```

Query is based on 3 tables. 
Tables : 
1. Users 
2. Files 
3. Answers

- Username column in the users table is identity.
- Each user can have many or none Files
- Each user can have many or none Answers.

**Thank you!
Dan**

Comment: INT_GENDER?? Why not bool if all you are using is Male or Female. Also for best performance, use a stored proc. This is because stored procedures cache the execution plan which is very useful for quick retrieval.

Comment: thanks.
1. INT_GENDER can be 0,1,2.
2. I prefer to stay with linq , i know i can also make it a complied query , but i was looking to write a better query first.

Comment: @AboutDev Prepared queries (like the one used in LINQ to SQL) also have their execution plan cached. The urban legend about this superiority of stored procs is getting old.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my modest attempt to decipher this in plain T-SQL. Hope this helps.

```
SELECT u.username, f.id, a.value, a.approved
FROM users AS u
     JOIN files AS f ON u.username = f.username
     JOIN answers AS a ON a.username = u.username
     JOIN questions AS q ON a.q_id = q.id      
WHERE u.gender = @INT_GENDER
      AND u.age > 25
      AND f.approved = 1
      AND a.approved = 1
      AND q.type = 1
```